# Python IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, machine-learning

Before I explain my situation, I would like to inform that this codes is not mine and I am using only as reference for experimental purposes. These codes belongs to the rightful [owner](https://github.com/llSourcell/One-Shot-Learning-Demo/blob/master/demo_classification.py#L3).

I was trying to experiment with Machine Learning. And I used this code in order to get an idea about One-Shot Learning.

```
import numpy as np
import copy
from scipy.ndimage import imread
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

nrun = 20
fname_label = 'class_labels.txt'

def LIAP(fn):
    I = imread(fn, flatten=True)
    I = np.array(I, dtype=bool)
    I = np.logical_not(I)
    (row, col) = I.nonzero()
    D = np.array(row, col)
    D = np.transpose(D)
    D = D.astype(float)
    D = D.shape[0]
    mean = np.mean(D, axis=0)
    for i in mean(D, axis=0):
        D[i, :] = D[i, :] - mean
    return D

def MHD(itemA, itemB):
    D = cdist(itemA, itemB)
    mindist_A = D.min(axis=1)
    mindist_B = D.min(axis=0)
    mean_A = np.mean(mindist_A)
    mean_B = np.mean(mindist_B)
    return max(mean_A, mean_B)

def classification_run(folder, f_load, f_cost, ftype='cost'):
    assert ((ftype == 'cost') | (ftype == 'score'))

    with open(folder+'/'+fname_label) as f:
        content = f.read().splitlines()
    pairs = (line.split() for line in content)
    test_files = [pair[0] for pair in pairs]
    train_files = [pair[1] for pair in pairs]
    answers_files = copy.copy(train_files)
    test_files.sort()
    train_files.sort()
    ntrain = len(train_files)
    ntest = len(test_files)

    train_items = [f_load(f) for f in train_files]
    test_items = [f_load(f) for f in test_files]

    costM = np.zeros((ntest, ntrain), float)
    for i in range(ntest):
        for c in range(ntrain):
            costM[i, c] = f_cost(test_items[i], train_items[c])
    if ftype == 'cost':
        YHAT = np.argmin(costM, axis=1)
    elif ftype == 'score':
        YHAT = np.argmax(costM, axis=1)
    else:
        assert False

    correct = 0.0
    for i in range(ntest):
        if train_files[YHAT[i]] == answers_files[i]:
            correct += 1.0
    pcorrect = 100 * correct / ntest
    perror = 100 - pcorrect
    return perror

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print 'One-shot classification demo with Modified Hausdorff Distance'
    perror = np.zeros(nrun)
    for r in range(1, nrun+1):
        rs = str(r)
        if len(rs) == 1:
            rs = '0' + rs
        perror[r-1] = classification_run('run'+rs, LIAP, MHD, 'cost')
        print " run " + str(r) + " (error" + str(perror[r-1]) + "%)"
    total = np.mean(perror)
    print " average error" + str(total) + "%"
```

But apparently, i received an IOError.

```
One-shot classification demo with Modified Hausdorff Distance
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 121, in <module>
    'cost')
  File "demo.py", line 31, in classification_run
    with open(os.path.join(path_to_all_runs, folder, fname_label)) as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/gilangrilhami/Documents/MachineLearning/ml_projects/one/all_runs/run01/class_labels.txt'
```

As far as I know, it supposed to make a folder for every run and create it's own 'class_labels.txt'. I tried to read the comment section just in case I missed something and anybody has the same issue. But I couldn't find anything related. I would like to find a solution or perhaps I've missed something.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no creation code for this txt file. You should check out the whole repo and use it to run one of their runs, where this file already exists or create this file manually.